# Yocto recipe and wheel installation

Tags: pip, yocto

I need to install specific .whl (orjson) file in my recipe so I would not have any traces of pip on the target machine. I already downloaded the whl from Pypi and placed it inside of ./files directory of my new layer recipe so I could easily install it without fetching. I just want to keep the final image relatively small. Unfortunately I can't understand what is next: how should I construct the do_install() and other steps so to install python 11 wheel with native (host) python 11. Is it possible to download wheel file directly with all dependencies and install it? Could you please shed some light here.
Thanks.

As an example, I tried to be as direct as it is here, but I could not figure out how to invoke pip.

```
`DESCRIPTION = "NVIDIA's version of Python Torch"
HOMEPAGE = "https://nvidia.com"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"

inherit setuptools3

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python3 \
                  python3-pip \
                  "

SRC_URI = "\
        file://torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl \
        file://LICENSE \
"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "9ec85425a64ca266abbfdeddbe92fb18"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "3b9b8f944962aaf550460409e9455d6d6b86083510b985306a8012d01d730b8b"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "(tegra)"
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE_comp = "(-)"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://../LICENSE;md5=acf4d595f99e159bf31797aa872aef57"

S = "${WORKDIR}/${PN}-${PV}"

do_configure() {
        :
}

do_compile() {
        :
}

do_install() {
        pip3 install torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_aarch64.whl
}

PACKAGE_ARCH = "jetson_nano"`
```