# Yocto recipe for installing whl

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

I am attempting to create a Yocto recipe to install a whl file that is pre-downloaded.

Folder structure:

```
python3-spiker/
  python3-spiker.4.0.0.bb
  files/
     spiker_python-4.0.0-linux-aarch64.whl
```

I have tried two different approaches [Yocto recipe and wheel installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77229595/yocto-recipe-and-wheel-installation) and [Yocto recipe python whl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660051/yocto-recipe-python-whl-package) and both result in files not being found during different stages. I am doing the install this way to prevent PIP being needed on target.

Hopefully someone with more experience can show me where I am going wrong here.

```
COMPATIBLE_HOST = "aarch64*"

SUMMARY = "SPIKER Python3 SDK"
DESCRIPTION = "SPIKER Python3 SDK for aarch64"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI = "file://spiker_python-4.0.0-linux-aarch64.whl"

inherit setuptools3

DEPENDS += "python3 \
            python3-pip-native \
"

do_install() {
    pip3 install ${WORKDIR}/files/spiker_python-4.0.0-linux-aarch64.whl
}
```

Results in error during do_compile: .../cortexa72-cortexa53-tdx-linux/python3-spiker/4.0.0-r0/python3-spiker-4.0.0/setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

All folders are there but the `setup.py` file is missing.

```
COMPATIBLE_HOST = "aarch64*"

SUMMARY = "SPIKER Python3 SDK"
DESCRIPTION = "SPIKER Python3 SDK for aarch64"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI = "file://spiker_python-4.0.0-linux-aarch64.whl"

inherit python3-dir

DEPENDS += "python3"

PV = "4.0.0"

do_unpack[depends] += "unzip-native:do_populate_sysroot"

FILES:${PN} += "\
    ${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/spiker_python \
    ${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/spiker_python-${PV}.dist-info \
"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/spiker_python
    install -d ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/spiker_python-${PV}.dist-info

    install -m 644 ${S}/spiker_python/* ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/spiker_python/
    install -m 644 ${S}/spiker_python-${PV}.dist-info/* ${D}${libdir}/${PYTHON_DIR}/site-packages/spiker_python-${PV}.dist-info/
}
```

Results in error during do_install:

| install: cannot stat '.../cortexa72-cortexa53-tdx-linux/python3-spiker/4.0.0-r0/python3-spiker-4.0.0/spiker_python/*': No such file or directory

Everything is there until the last directory: `/spiker_python/*`

Comment: Is the project listed on [pypi](https://pypi.org)? If so, you can use the bbclass [pypi](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/classes.html#pypi) and specify the project name. Or do you really want to install this .whl manually?

Comment: The package is on pypi but hasnt been updated in 2-3 years. The most recent version there is 2.4 and the current package is 4.0.0.